# How to find NAs in groups and create new column for data frame

Tags: r, aggregate, na

I have a data frame consisting of an "ID" column and a "Diff" column. The ID column is responsible for marking groups of corresponding Diff values.
An example looks like this:

```
structure(list(ID = c(566, 566, 789, 789, 789, 487, 487, 11, 
11, 189, 189), Diff = c(100, 277, 529, 43, NA, 860, 780, 445, 
NA, 578, 810)), .Names = c("ID", "Diff"), row.names = c(9L, 10L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 25L, 26L, 51L, 52L, 62L, 63L), class = "data.frame")
```

My goal is to search each group for NAs in the Diff column and create a new column, that has either a "True" or "False" value for each row, depending if the corresponding group has an NA in Diff.

I tried

```
x <- aggregate(Diff ~ ID, data, is.na)
```

and

```
y <- aggregate(Diff ~ ID, data, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
```

The idea was to merge the result depending on ID. However, none of the above created a useful result. I know R can do it … and after searching for quite a while I ask you how :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*You have two viable strategies already, but here is another which may be conceptually easier to follow if you are relatively new to R and aren't familiar with the way plyr works.*)

I often need to know how many `NA`s I have in different variables, so here is a convenience function I use standard:

```
sna <- function(x){
  sum(is.na(x))
}
```

From there, I sometimes use `aggregate()`, but sometimes I find [?summaryBy](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/doBy/docs/summaryBy) in the [doBy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doBy/index.html) package to be more convenient.  Here's an example:

```
library(doBy)
z <- summaryBy(Diff~ID, data=my.data, FUN=sna)
z
   ID Diff.sna
1  11        1
2 189        0
3 487        0
4 566        0
5 789        1
```

After this, you just need to use [?merge](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) and convert the count of `NA`s to a logical to get your final data frame:

```
my.data          <- merge(my.data, z, by="ID")
my.data$Diff.sna <- my.data$Diff.sna>0
my.data
    ID Diff Diff.sna
1   11  445     TRUE
2   11   NA     TRUE
3  189  578    FALSE
4  189  810    FALSE
5  487  860    FALSE
6  487  780    FALSE
7  566  100    FALSE
8  566  277    FALSE
9  789  529     TRUE
10 789   43     TRUE
11 789   NA     TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume all answers are suitable and will lead to the expected results. However, this one was the easiest to follow - as mentioned in the introduction :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `plyr` and `ddply`

```
require(plyr)
ddply(data, .(ID), transform, na_diff = any(is.na(Diff)))
##     ID Diff na_diff
## 1   11  445    TRUE
## 2   11   NA    TRUE
## 3  189  578   FALSE
## 4  189  810   FALSE
## 5  487  860   FALSE
## 6  487  780   FALSE
## 7  566  100   FALSE
## 8  566  277   FALSE
## 9  789  529    TRUE
## 10 789   43    TRUE
## 11 789   NA    TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

A very similar solution to @dickoa except in `base`:

```
do.call(rbind,by(data,data$ID,function(x)transform(x,na_diff=any(is.na(Diff)))))
#         ID Diff na_diff
# 11.51   11  445    TRUE
# 11.52   11   NA    TRUE
# 189.62 189  578   FALSE
# 189.63 189  810   FALSE
# 487.25 487  860   FALSE
# 487.26 487  780   FALSE
# 566.9  566  100   FALSE
# 566.10 566  277   FALSE
# 789.20 789  529    TRUE
# 789.21 789   43    TRUE
# 789.22 789   NA    TRUE
```

Similarly, you could avoid `transform` with:

```
data$na_diff<-with(data,by(Diff,ID,function(x) any(is.na(x)))[as.character(ID)])
```

Comment: Nice. You could simplify your code like this `do.call(rbind, by(data, data$ID, transform, na_diff = any(is.na(Diff))))`